# Reference attribute enum value

Tags: android, android-xml

Is it possible to reference an *enum* value when supplying style parameters?
For example, we can do:

```xml
<!-- layouts.xml -->
<TextView
    android:text="@string/str" />

<!-- values.xml -->
<item type="string" name="str">hi</item>
```

This works fine with strings, integers, dimensions and so on but I need to reference an *enum* value - for example the `visibility` attribute. I'm looking for something like:

```xml
<!-- layouts.xml -->
<TextView
    android:visibility="@????/viz" />

<!-- values.xml -->
<item type="?????" name="viz">gone</item>
```

`visibility` is only an example - it could be any other enum based attribute.

The only workaround I have found so far is by using *styles*

```xml
<!-- layouts.xml -->
<TextView
    android:style="@styles/theStyle" />

<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="theStyle">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

But this is somehow restrictive because it becomes increasingly complicated if you need to use *real* styles with the TextViews and this *special* style which is only used to control a single attribute.

Another option would be if there is a way to reference individual style items. Something like:

```xml
<TextView
    android:visibility="@styles/theStyle/visibility" />
```

But I think that the above is even less likely to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each enum is actually a set of named integers.
For example, `visibility` attribute is declared as follows:

```
<attr name="visibility">
    <enum name="visible" value="0" />
    <enum name="invisible" value="1" />
    <enum name="gone" value="2" />
</attr>
```

So you can reference to enum item directly by its value. Something like this:

```
<!-- values.xml -->
<item name="viz" type="integer">1</item>

<!-- layouts.xml -->
<TextView
    android:visibility="@integer/viz"/>
```

I just checked it on my phone and it works well.

Comment: Thank you! Works great! You still need the Android sources to find out the enum values, but still much better than the `style` solution. And just out of curiosity - do you think there is a way to reference single item from existing style? Something like `android:visibility="@styles/theStyle/visibility"` ?

Comment: I don't really think that it's possible

Comment: How about Flag item?