# What is visibility in XML? dimen, string, etc (Android)

Tags: android, xml, visibility, attr

I want to have different visibility for each version (JB, KK and L). Then, I have some attr.xml files for each version, before I was using dimen value to set its height to 0 or X dpi, but now I need to remove the view.

What is visibility? is not a dimen, is not a string... how can I get it from my attr to my view with `android:visibility="@XXXXXXX/myViewVisibility"`

With the height I use `android:visibility="@dimen/myViewHeight"` and it works perfectly...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work with `@string/anyOfYourStrings`?

Comment: @ataulm with string doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference attribute enum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176563/reference-attribute-enum-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an enum. You can find the definition for the enum in the framework's [attrs.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-5.0.2_r1/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml) (line 2163).

You can use an integer reference if you really want to use a resource reference, but I don't recommend it in case (for whatever reason) those constants change in the future. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- 2 corresponds to "gone" -->
    <integer name="my_visibility">2</integer>
</resources>

<View
    visibility="@integer/my_visiblity" />
```

A style would also work for version-specific visibility, like so:

```
<style name="MyViewStyle">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>

<View
    style="@style/MyViewStyle" />
```

Comment: I'm going to try, thank you for your reply. I tried to search visibility in developer.android.com, but I didnt see

Comment: @Dahnark you can also see this if you open the generated `R.java` file. `visibility` is a constant defined in the `attr` class which contain all the attributes that have enumerated values. Probably works with `@dimen/something` because this resolves to an integer but not `@string/something` because that does not resolve to an integer.

Comment: But if I use a dimen, I have to search what is the dimen to gone and visible, using the word gone or visible, doesn't work

Comment: How can I use the style way to avoid possible changes in the future of that values?

Comment: I added an example. There are some caveats with styles, mainly that each View can only have one style.

Comment: OKay, in the stack overflow app doesnt appear your code, in web yes, sorry for the comment before.

Comment: Save some time: `visible=0`, `invisible=1`, `gone=2` :D